# scrollview in portrait and landscape in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, landscape-portrait

In my current application am using scrollview but facing some issues,when view in portrait to landscape mode or vsv. I am allocating the frame for scroll view is (10,10,1024,550) and (10,10,1024,820). I am using following method for set the frame.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
         {

                 [self LandscpeFrame];
        }
    else 
    {
                [self PotraitFrame];
        }
}
```

But when changing the mode it can not work properly. How to set the frame for a scrollview for supporting both landscape and portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `LandscapeFrame` and `PortraitFrame` methods I can't be sure, but are you setting `contentSize` in both of those methods when you're changing the frame?

Comment: scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 1024, 550) for landscape and 
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 1024, 820); for potrait

Comment: No.am setting only frame size.how to set content size.please help.

Comment: Try setting `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);`